# aspectj-maven-plugin could not create ***$AjcClosure*.class

Tags: aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

my maven project used spring aop, everything worked fine.now because *blablabla*, i need to use aspectj, i add aspectj dependency and aspectj maven plugin in config

```
    <aspectj.version>1.8.2</aspectj.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <complianceLevel>${java-version}</complianceLevel>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>       
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <sources><source><basedir>src/main/java</basedir></source></sources>
            </configuration>                
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <phase>process-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal><!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

when maven builds the project, the output below:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7:compile (default) @ wolverine-ris ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[WARNING] Missing message: configure.invalidClasspathSection in: org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.messages
<unknown source file>:<no line information>

[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult
```

and i think the target class should be output multiple classes after compiled
just like this:
[expected generated classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzBTj.png)

but in my situation only one class is weaved.

when i invoke the controller, there's an null pointer execption.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
            at com.*.*.*.hotel.controller.HotelController.getHotelFLag_aroundBody1$advice(HotelController.java:79) ~[HotelController.class:na]
            at com.*.*.*.hotel.controller.HotelController.getHotelFLag(HotelController.java:1) ~[HotelController.class:na]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) [servlet-api.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at com.**.web.filter.AccessOriginFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessOriginFilter.java:34) [nfbird-spring-mvc-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at com.**.web.filter.DecodingFilter.doFilterInternal(DecodingFilter.java:47) [nfbird-spring-mvc-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.40]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.40]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_30]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_30]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_30]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

==========================UPDATE 1==========================

i changed aspectj maven plugin version to 1.6 and ${aspectj.version} to 1.7.4, the warning message didn't appear

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.6:compile (default) @ wolverine-ris ---
Downloading: http://nexus.**.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.7.4/aspectjtools-1.7.4.pom
Downloaded: http://nexus.**.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.7.4/aspectjtools-1.7.4.pom (1021 B at 26.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://nexus.**.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.7.4/aspectjtools-1.7.4.jar
Downloaded: http://nexus.**.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.7.4/aspectjtools-1.7.4.jar (9784 KB at 38518.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult com.**.train.controller.TrainTicketController.queryTrainTickets(com.**.train.actor.message.QueryTrainTicketVo))' in Type 'com.**.train.controller.TrainTicketController' (TrainTicketController.java:47) advised by around advice from 'com.**.kafka.aspect.RequestAspect' (RequestAspect.java:41)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult com.**.train.controller.TrainTicketController.queryTrainTicketsByTrainId(com.**.train.actor.message.QueryTrainTicketVo))' in Type 'com.**.train.controller.TrainTicketController' (TrainTicketController.java:72) advised by around advice from 'com.**.kafka.aspect.RequestAspect' (RequestAspect.java:41)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult com.**.hotelflow.controller.StreamHotelController.queryHotelsForPlayPrd(com.**.hotel.actor.message.QueryHotelVo))' in Type 'com.**.hotelflow.controller.StreamHotelController' (StreamHotelController.java:33) advised by around advice from 'com.**.kafka.aspect.RequestAspect' (RequestAspect.java:41)
....
```

but when i invoke the controller, there's still an null pointer execption(posted above).

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem, the npe exception is due to an incorrect annotation.
I wrote it like that when i used spring aop, and lately i didn't change it

```
@Aspect
public class RequestAspect extends AbstractAspect {
    @Injected
    private KafkaLog kafkaLog;

    ....
}
```

I use another way to get kafkaLog bean instead of annotation, everything is ok, so i don't care *$AjcClosure*.class stuff now.^_^